# Using Multiple asset catalogs with one in a cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So i have a cocoa pod which contains the platform layer for our mobile apis.

We have two mobile apps which both use the cocoa pod but also use a lot of the same image assets.

Is it ok to create an asset catalog within the cocoa pod and use that in the actual application? And if so do i need to specify in the build targets that i am using two asset catalogs?

I don't really need two really. Theres the one in the pod and one that gets built with the application template. I really just want to use the one in the cocoa pod.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`resources`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resources) for this. This way you can use the same assets in each application. You can have as many `xcassets` files as you want per target.